# Для чего используют данное CSS-свойство?

Tags: css

Встретил такой код:

```
html{
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Для чего это используется, и когда использовать?

Comment: Можете почитать тут https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text-size-adjust` управляет отображением текста на мобильнике (iOS).

Может принимать значения:

- `auto` (текст на мобильнике подстраивается автоматически);
- `none` (размер текста на мобильнике не изменяется);
- `60%` (или другой процент) означает желаемый относительный размер текста на мобильнике.

[Хабра](https://habrahabr.ru/post/133465/)

[developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust)

Comment: Третья статья про другое свойство. Это свойство, я так понял, нужно использовать, если верстка не адаптивная?

Comment: @HamSter я узнал тебя маска :-) Ник красивый!

Comment: @Alexandr_T, ;) только никому не слова)